# Testing ReactJS component methods with enzyme shallow - function returns undefined instead of true

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component with the following method that calls a function set via props:

```
    class OrderDish extends Component {
        static propTypes = {
            image: React.PropTypes.any,
            order: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            removeFromOrder: React.PropTypes.func,
            addCommentToOrder: React.PropTypes.func,
            canOrder: React.PropTypes.bool
        };

    handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            this.props.addCommentToOrder(e.target.value, this.props.order, true);
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { order, canOrder } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="Order-dish">
                <div className="Order">
                    <div className="Order-extra-info">
                        <TextField
                            className='Order-dish-comment'
                            ref="comment"
                            id={order.entry.type}
                            value={order.comment ? order.comment : ''}
                            onChange={this.handleCommentChange}
                            fullWidth
                            onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
                            disabled={!canOrder}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default OrderDish;
```

Now the first thing that I would like to test is the method itself - if I pass in the `key: 'Enter'`, will it try to call the `addCommentToOrder` prop?

So I made a [mock function](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#jestfnimplementation) with jest that returns true, and tried to pass it as a prop, then [call the method](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/208) and see what happens:

```
it('Test field should call handleKeyPress on key down', () => {
    const mockKeyPressFN = jest.fn(() => { return true; });
    let orderDish = shallow(<OrderDish order={mockOrder} addCommentToOrder={mockKeyPressFN}/>);
    expect(orderDish.instance().handleKeyPress({key: 'Enter', target: {value: 'mock'}})).toBe(true);
  });
```

But my test fails with the following output:

> ```
> expect(received).toBe(expected)
>
> Expected value to be (using ===):
>   true
> Received:
>   undefined
> ```

```
console.log(orderDish.instance());
```

Returns the method as a function:

```
handleKeyPress: [Function]
```

This:

```
console.log(orderDish.instance().handleKeyPress({key: 'Enter', target:{value: 'mock'}}));
```

Does not log anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you exporting your component?

Comment: Added more component info (only the code that seems relevant), and the export statement at the bottom. it's export default OrderDish;

Comment: The code looks sensible. How are you running your tests? Have you stuck some break points in to see? Have you considered simulating the keyDown event and spying on the function that way?

Comment: I usually just run npm jest to run the tests. I though that I would try to test the method in isolation, and then try to simulate the event in a separate test. I could try some breakpoints in WebStorm, but at the moment I think that the function is not getting called at all on the instance. Is there a way for me to check what the instance returns?

Comment: You could console.log(orderDish.instance()), you could also console.log() in handleKeyPress and the jest function to see if any of those are being invoked. I run unit tests with karma so you are able to debug and set breakpoints in chrome, which is very handy

Comment: Edited the main question with the console logs. Basically I was just able to determine that the method is there but not much else.

Comment: Does jest.fn(() => { console.log('Jest'); return true; }); log anything?

Comment: So I changed the mock function to: const mockKeyPressFN = jest.fn(() => { console.log('jest') });. I see the console log, but the test output is still the same (expected undefined to be true). So I guess the assertion is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132787/discussion-between-t-mitchell-and-miha-sustersic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expect(orderDish.instance().handleKeyPress({key: 'Enter', target: {value: 'mock'}})).toBe(true);
```

You are testing handleKeyPress()'s return value, but the function doesn't return anything.

It's mockKeyPressFN that is returning a value, and presumably what you want to test.

You can test the return value, or the fact that it was called, or both - https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html

for example:

```
expect(mockKeyPressFN.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```